# Java-Why these two are giving different outputs for calculating prime numbers of form k^2+1?

Tags: java, math, time-complexity, primes

I wrote two programs for my lab work for finding primes of form k^2 +1 less than 1000000 in two different ways to have better time complexity in 2nd program but i am getting different answers in both. 
Can someone tell me why?In first we are first checking if its a prime(n) and then checking if its perfect square(n-1).
In second we are directly checking form k^2+1 for k less than sqrt(1000000)-1 and increasing the count.
But both produce different answers.Which method is right for counting primes of form k^2+1 under 1000000?

First Program

```
 public class KSqPlus1
    {

    public static void main(String [] args)
  { 
     int k = 2;
    for (int n = 11; n < 1000000; n += 2)
       if (isPrime (n))
         if (isPerfectSquare (n - 1))
         {   k ++; 

       }

     System.out.println (k);  

  }

   public static boolean isPrime(int n)
   {
     for(int divisor=3;divisor*divisor<=n;divisor+=2)
         if(n%divisor==0)
           return false;
        return true;
   }
  public static boolean isPerfectSquare (int n)
     {
          for(int divisor=2;divisor*divisor<=n;divisor+=2)
         if(divisor * divisor < n) continue;
          else if (divisor * divisor == n ) return true;
          return false;

     }
 }
```

2nd Program

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class PrimeArrays1
{

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {

    int count=2;int k;
    for(k=3;k<(Math.sqrt(1000000)-1);k++)
    { int x=k*k+1;
     if(isPrime(x))
     {
      count++;

     }
    }
     System.out.println(count);



  }

   public static boolean isPrime(double n)
   {
     for(int divisor=3;divisor*divisor<=n;divisor+=2)
     if(n%divisor==0)
     return false;
     return true;
   }

 }
```

EDIT::
Below is the correct isPrime function..now the programs are giving same answer :)

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n)
   {
     for(int divisor=2;divisor*divisor<=n;divisor+=1)
         if(n%divisor==0)
           return false;
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: Well, one difference - the `d` that you print in both cases is not the same think - in one case it's the prime number and in the other it's the number being squared and added 1. Do you get the same count in both?

Comment: d is just for debugging purpose.i just forgot to remove it.other than that it has not significance. removed it now

Comment: So what are the results you get?

Comment: 112 for first program and 242 for second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method

```
  public static boolean isPerfectSquare (int n)
     {
          for(int divisor=2;divisor*divisor<=n;divisor+=2)
         if(divisor * divisor < n) continue;
          else if (divisor * divisor == n ) return true;
          return false;

     }
```

will return `true` only if `n` is a square of an even number. I guess you want to check if it is a square of any number.

Similarly, the method

```
   public static boolean isPrime(double n)
   {
     for(int divisor=3;divisor*divisor<=n;divisor+=2)
     if(n%divisor==0)
     return false;
     return true;
   }
```

Does not check for factors of 2, so 4, 8, ... return `true`.

Comment: OP is only checking odd numbers to be prime, so isPrime is fine, but isPerfectSquare is flawed. Since it doesn't get passed the potential prime, but one less, which is always an even number.

Comment: @JensSchauder counter example: k=3, x=10 is passed to isPrime in program 2.

Comment: i think both the functions are right. i want to find if a number that is both (prime and of form k^2+1 for any k) for example 17(for k=4) -it is prime and 17-1=16 is perfect square.so yes isPerfectSquare will always take prime-1 type of numbers i.e even and  for isPrime Function- even numbers are not prime except 2

Comment: got the answer.the problem was with isPrime Function it was not checking for factors of 2